# How do i find bitcoinadress?

Tags: address

I am wondering where do I find the bitcoin address?
I want to buy some bitcoins but I don't know what to put in for bitcoin adress.

Comment: It depends what wallet you're using. What kind of wallet do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a bitcoin address in order to send and receive bitcoins. To do this, choose a bitcoin exchanger to set up one.